# ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis in SQL

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to run this SQL query in java

```
String query = "update table_name set refresh_date=to_date('01-SEP-2013','dd-mon-yyyy') where colomn_name like '%my_col%'"
jdbc.execute(query);
```

I'm getting the error

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I have looked at other similar questions on stackoverflow but cannot figure out what's wrong here.

Comment: You're not using corresponding quotes. Why are they different?

Comment: Looks you are not using correct quotes. Between your 'L' key and '\' key. :)

Comment: @Ketan in which keyboard ? ;)

Comment: Maybe your format's capitalization is the problem. You should try using `MON` (since your month is in all capitals).

Comment: Did you try my suggestion ? Did you find a solution to your problem ? Do you care sharing it with the community ;)

Comment: The problem was indeed with quotes which were typed wrong.. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some invalid quotes. You need to match them like this

```
update table_name set refresh_date=to_date('01-SEP-2013','dd-mon-yyyy') where colomn_name like '%my_col%'
```

Comment: What exactly did you change? I put yours and the OP's queries next to each other, vertically, yet I don't see the difference.

Comment: The OP originally had different matching quotes which he changed within 5 minutes of posting - that why you don't see any difference in the revisions :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong quotes. Try this:

```
update table_name 
  set refresh_date=to_date('01-SEP-2013','dd-mon-yyyy') 
  where colomn_name like '%my_col%'
```